# How to set a relative path/How to use $(SolutionDir)

Tags: c++, path, relative-path

I'm trying to make a project compile no matter where it is cloned, but I don't know how to write the relative path in relation to the solution location, for now this is how it looks

[image]

I tried something with $(SolutionDir) but i don't know how to go one step back from it and into the libraries folder as shown in the current absolute paths. Can someone explain what should i do or show an example ?

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)\..\libraries\...`. Also, consider using vcpkg

Comment: can you write it as an answer so i can mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go one step back from a `$(SolutionDir)` you can write `$(SolutionDir)\..\`.

You also can go deeper and create a property sheet for your library, so that if you need to use this library in another project, you would need to include only one `.prop`-file into your `.vcxproj`.

Assuming the library name is `cereal` and property sheet is located in `libraries`, the `.prop`-file would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\cereal\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\cereal\$(Platform)\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>cereal.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Then to use it in a project, you add this in your `.vcxproj` (you can also use gui for this):

```xml
<ImportGroup Condition="..." Label="PropertySheets">
  ...
  <Import Project="..\..\..\libraries\cereal.props" />
</ImportGroup>
```

You can also greatly ease your life by using some package manager, namely [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows) because of it integration with Visual Studio.